# NetworkInfo.IsConnected Object reference not set to an instance of an object on xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, connectivity

I'm trying to detect connectivity with Xamarin Android.

When i'm connected on wifi or roaming, i don't have any errors.

But when i'm not connected on internet, i'm having a System.NullReferenceException error and the app crash.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;

bool isOnline = info.IsConnected; //error is here
```

Normally, the bool isConnected should turn to false. But i don't know why it's on null.

How can i fix that?

Comment: if you aren't connected to the internet, connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo is more than likely returning null, so trying to access property IsConnected of a null object is producing `NullReferenceException`, wrap your `bool isOnline = info.IsConnected in a try catch and catch NullReferenceException or check to see if info == null before doing isOnline = info.IsConnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you aren't connected to the internet, `connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo` is more than likely returning null, so trying to access property `IsConnected` of a null object is producing `NullReferenceException`

Quick fix:

```
//Use a ternary expression to evaluate whether info equals null, if so set
//bool to false, else use the IsConnected property
bool isOnline = info == null ? false : info.IsConnected;
```